# Add Collection view to one of tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to add collection view to one of cell from my table view 
but I don't know how to setting up this layout,anyone could give me the direction or idea to implement thanks

Comment: While this can be done, could you explain further on what you are trying to achieve? There might be a simpler solution.

Comment: i searched on internet almost tutorial is teach us how to achieve collection view mix table view ,but i don't want to all of my table view  cell embed collection view  i just want to only one of cell from table view embed collection view~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really simple task to do:

1. Create a custom cell and corresponding class by subclassing
   `UITableViewCell`.
2. Add the `UICollectionView` to the cell you just created. Connect the `IBoutlet`, `DataSource` and `Delegate` to the subclass of the `UITableViewCell` you just created.
3. Implement the `DataSource` and `Delegate` methods in the `UITableViewCell` subclass.
4. Add the custom `UITableViewCell` to the `tableView` which you require in the required position.

[**Here is a really nice tutorial for adding custom cells to table view.**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift)

**EDIT**

If you want to add the cell only at a particular index in the tableview, just use an `if` condition in the `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` Like following:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) //Your required row
    {
        CustomCellWithCollection *cellWithCollection = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"yourIdentifierForCellWithCollection" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cellWithCollection == nil){
           //Create your cell here
        }
        // do your logic here.
        return cellWithCollection;
    }

    NormalCell *normalCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"yourIdentifierForNormalCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (normalCell == nil){
       // Create your normal cell here
    }

    // do your logic for normal cell here


    return normalCell;

}
```

Comment: i know this way to create tableview mix collection view but i want to only one table view cell add collection view is it possible to achieve

Comment: Yes, in the `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, check the indexPath.row and then return the cell only for the required indexPath and return normal cell for other cells.

Comment: YES~~~but i don't know how to set up in this method sorry i'm a Rookies Ios developer

Comment: See the tutorial I have mentioned in the answer. After loading the tableview if something doesn't work ask it specifically. The entire code required to meet your condition cannot be posted here. :-)

Comment: Thanks.It's make me struggle for a while.